# Authorization model for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authorization

I am building a project management app and I am not sure which is the best/correct authorization model to implement given I am new to Rails (and programming in general). Here is what I am trying to do.

I want to be able to add a "client" to the application and then multiple projects to a client. I would like to be able to add users (that are essentially representatives of the client) to view that clients multiple projects but not other clients. I intend on having controllers for time tracking, notes, comments and images all to be associated with both clients and project of that client.

In addition, I would like to set up the account to control who is able to have one. I don't need the user to establish an account on their own.

Does that make sense?

Comment: This not called Authentication... This is called Authorization.

Comment: In case it's not clear from the above... Authentication is about determining accurately who someone is. Authorization is about determining/controlling what they're allowed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are mentioning is called Authorization not Authentication, anyway:

I would suggest [acl9](http://github.com/be9/acl9) for authorization and [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) for authentication.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this answers. What are the reasons that you suggest acl9 and authlogic.

Comment: There are others available that are also well-used. [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is #1 at the moment (June 10, 2013) for [authorization](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization) in Ruby Toolbox's list. And [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is #1 in Ruby Toolbox's [authentication](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication) list.

Answer (score 3):

These (free) [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?search=authlogic) should give you some food for thought. There are lots of great RubyGems/plugins out there for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

[The Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com) gives you an overview of tools and their popularity in the rails community (rated by watchers and forkers on GitHub). As you can see there, the suggested plugins restful_authentication and authlogic are almost on the same level.

Answer (score 1):

[Restful Authentication](http://wiki.github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication) is still the golden standard for user authentication in ruby on rails.

Comment: This became too old now... ppl moved to authlogic which is far better.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Authorization plug-in](http://github.com/DocSavage/rails-authorization-plugin) in the past and like it because it gives some nice meta methods such as:

```
  user.is_eligible_for_what   --> returns array of authorizable objects for which user has role "eligible"
  user.is_moderator_of? group --> returns true/false
  user.is_moderator_of group  --> sets user to have role "moderator" for object group.
  user.is_administrator       --> sets user to have role "administrator" not really tied to any object.
```

There's also a brand new [RailsCast on CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [AuthLogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) for authentication (logging in users and making sure they are who they claim to be) and [declarative_authorization](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) for authorization (making sure they have access to resources). See Ryan Bates' excellent Railscasts on [AuthLogic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic) and [restful_authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization) for more info.